# Depends: exim vs mail-transport-agent

Tags: packaging, postfix, smtp, sendmail, mta

I am creating a .deb installation package for our software, which depends on a valid SMTP server being installed. Currently the `control` file states:

```
Depends: mail-transport-agent
```

However one Debian user complained that the package wouldn't install, probably because he has `exim` installed. Now I am a little confused. Is exim a valid MTA? If so, why doesn't it "provide" the virtual package `mail-transport-agent`?

If I edit my `control` file to state:

```
Depends: exim | mail-transport-agent
```

Can I assume a working SMTP server will be available when the `exim` package is installed? Or is `exim` not really a replacement for postfix, sendmail, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exim is a full MTA, just like Postfix.

The several flavours of Exim, such as `exim4-daemon-light`, all have a nice

```
Provides: [...] mail-transport-agent
```

line there.

If your user complains it won't install, I see these obvious causes:

- `sudo dpkg -i package.deb` will result in a failure if dependencies aren't met, just like will happen with any other package with dependencies. He has to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to satisfy them and complete the installation, but he might not know he has to do this.

  Solution: ask full output of his installation attempt and it will probably hint on running some fix-broken command.
- He has installed Exim from source and his package management tries to install it over his local install (and he refuses to do so - for a reason).

  Solution: make it a `Recommends:` instead of a hard `Depends:`, to relax the dependency a bit. Regular installation methods do install the recommended dependencies, but can be relaxed by the user, e.g. `--no-install-recommends` via `apt-get`.